# jQuery for loops not running function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop in jQuery that finds all 'img' elements and places a caption below them, according to the value of the element's 'caption' attribute. Whenever I run the loop below, I am left with no captions under any of the images.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.myimage').length; i++) {
    $('.myimage')[i].after('<h6>' + $('.myimage').attr('caption') + '</h6>');
};
```

However, when I run this code

```
$('.myimage').after('<h6>TEST</h6>');
```

the word 'TEST' appears below all of the images. Therefore I know my html is correct, I have no typos, and the selector is working, I just cannot get the for loop to work... What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('.myimage')[i]` returns a DOM element (not a jQuery object) so there is no `after` method. If you want to loop, simply use `.each`

```
$(".myimage").each(function() {
    //this refers to each image
    $(this).after('<h6>' + $(this).attr('caption') + '</h6>');
});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, this worked a treat! I didn't realise the $('.myimage')[i] would return a DOM object :P

Comment: @thatsimplekid -- Yep - you'll probably see something like `$("#myID")[0]` eventually - this is the same as `document.getElementById("myID")`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `.myimage` elements like this, using `.after()`'s callback function

```
$('.myimage').after(function(){
    return '<h6>' + $(this).attr('caption') + '</h6>';
});
```

One minor note, don't make up your own attributes. use the custom data attribute instead, like `data-caption="something"`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/314oLf9x/)**